# bokeh change circle colors with select or button

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to change the colour of my data points with bokeh. When I use a Hover tool this works fine. However, if I use the same callback function with a select or button tool it does not work. I guess this is beacause the change.emit() does not work in combination with a button or select?
How can I make my customJS work with a select or button tool?

```
callback3=CustomJS(args=dict(source2=source2,p2=p2),code=''' var source2=source2 var data3 = source2.data;

var color = data3['color'];
    var i, n = color.length;


    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    color[i] = 'blue';
    source2.change.emit();

    }

''' )
```

For my the hoover tool I use:

```
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback3, renderers=[d],mode='vline'))
```

For the button:

```
button = Button(label="Foo", button_type="success")
button.js_on_click(callback3)
```

When I use an alert in my callback this works also for the button and the select.

Comment: I can't really think of any reason, so what's necessary to investigate is a *complete, minimal reproducer*. I.e. a full script that  could be run, as-is, to see the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It actually really hellped me because I thought the cause is the change.emit() function. Now considering other reasons I realized that the problem was that I used show() two times. Once for the plot and a second time for the button and the select tool. So, I guess the problem was that like this the button was not really connected with the plot.

Comment: Ah, yes that is exactly correct. Can you self-answer and accept? Or delete the question. It helps the project to have fewer unanswered questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was not related to the change.emit(). The problem was that I used show separately for the plot and the button.